# Why am I seeing ARP requests for addresses outside of subnet

Tags: linux, networking, router, ipv4, arp

In my home network I have a router running Linux, with several VLANs coming into the same physical interface.
This is what things look like on the router:

```
➜ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:83:34:be:b0:9b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp1s0
    inet 80.x.x.x/20 metric 1024 brd x.x.x.255 scope global dynamic wan0
       valid_lft 67664sec preferred_lft 67664sec
    inet6 x:x:x:7000:1a86:1082:f9e:41bf/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 82400sec preferred_lft 22122sec
    inet6 x:x:x:a839:e160:a5b4:8601:7da8/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 85823sec preferred_lft 3023sec
    inet6 x:x:x:7000:8916:b7a2:bfc:3a40/64 scope global temporary deprecated dynamic
       valid_lft 82400sec preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 x:x:x:a839:3546:462d:74e4:e284/64 scope global temporary deprecated dynamic
       valid_lft 85823sec preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 x:x:x:7000:aef4:f2a8:62bc:8d8d/64 scope global temporary deprecated dynamic
       valid_lft 82400sec preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 x:x:x:7000:7e83:34ff:febe:b09b/64 metric 256 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr
       valid_lft 82400sec preferred_lft 68000sec
    inet6 x:x:x:a839:7c6d:b30d:b272:aebf/64 scope global temporary deprecated dynamic
       valid_lft 85823sec preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 x:x:x:a839:7e83:34ff:febe:b09b/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 85823sec preferred_lft 3023sec
    inet6 fe80::7e83:34ff:febe:b09b/64 scope link proto kernel_ll
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: lan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:83:34:be:b0:9c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s0
    inet 10.0.0.254/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global lan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 x:x:x:7001:3d40:df56:2ca8:e57/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 82400sec preferred_lft 63479sec
    inet6 x:x:x:7001:e887:62d5:fd5c:1183/64 scope global temporary deprecated dynamic
       valid_lft 82400sec preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 x:x:x:7001:7e83:34ff:febe:b09c/64 metric 256 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr
       valid_lft 82400sec preferred_lft 68000sec
    inet6 fe80::1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7e83:34ff:febe:b09c/64 scope link proto kernel_ll
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: guest@lan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:83:34:be:b0:9c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.20.254/24 brd 10.0.20.255 scope global guest
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 x:x:x:7020:384c:ffca:2bb7:af47/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 82400sec preferred_lft 64243sec
    inet6 x:x:x:7020:6f98:4139:a482:f1eb/64 scope global temporary deprecated dynamic
       valid_lft 82400sec preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 x:x:x:7020:7e83:34ff:febe:b09c/64 metric 256 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr
       valid_lft 82400sec preferred_lft 68000sec
    inet6 fe80::1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7e83:34ff:febe:b09c/64 scope link proto kernel_ll
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: iot@lan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:83:34:be:b0:9c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.10.254/24 brd 10.0.10.255 scope global iot
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 x:x:x:7010:e395:3d0:37d9:2be/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 82400sec preferred_lft 63524sec
    inet6 x:x:x:7010:5ccf:38dc:555e:a054/64 scope global temporary deprecated dynamic
       valid_lft 82400sec preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 x:x:x:7010:7e83:34ff:febe:b09c/64 metric 256 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr
       valid_lft 82400sec preferred_lft 68000sec
    inet6 fe80::1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7e83:34ff:febe:b09c/64 scope link proto kernel_ll
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: management@lan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:83:34:be:b0:9c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.30.254/24 brd 10.0.30.255 scope global management
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 x:x:x:7030:2e30:b0b1:8c51:a572/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 82400sec preferred_lft 63118sec
    inet6 x:x:x:7030:a321:4fcd:7e25:c127/64 scope global temporary deprecated dynamic
       valid_lft 82400sec preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 x:x:x:7030:7e83:34ff:febe:b09c/64 metric 256 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr
       valid_lft 82400sec preferred_lft 68000sec
    inet6 fe80::1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7e83:34ff:febe:b09c/64 scope link proto kernel_ll
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

➜ ip r
default via 80.x.x.x dev wan0 proto dhcp src x.x.x.x metric 1024
10.0.0.0/24 dev lan0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.254
10.0.10.0/24 dev iot proto kernel scope link src 10.0.10.254
10.0.20.0/24 dev guest proto kernel scope link src 10.0.20.254
10.0.30.0/24 dev management proto kernel scope link src 10.0.30.254
80.x.x.x/20 dev wan0 proto kernel scope link src 80.x.x.x metric 1024
80.x.x.x dev wan0 proto dhcp scope link src 80.x.x.x metric 1024
```

Everything works well on the `guest` and `iot` VLANs, the problem is with the `management` one.

That network has no other devices currently, but when I connect my laptop to it, by creating an interface with the right VLAN ID, I start seeing ARP requests for public IPs that are obviously outside of the subnet.

This is the laptop's network config:

```
➜ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: lan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:4d:ad:02:ac:fd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s20f0u1u2u1
    inet 10.0.0.55/24 metric 1024 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic lan0
       valid_lft 4768sec preferred_lft 4768sec
    inet6 x:x:x:7001:9667:e56d:71b:9ec8/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 3445sec preferred_lft 1645sec
    inet6 x:x:x:7001:f64d:adff:fe02:acfd/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 3445sec preferred_lft 1645sec
       valid_lft 3445sec preferred_lft 1645sec
    inet6 fe80::f64d:adff:fe02:acfd/64 scope link proto kernel_ll
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: lan1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:37:96:96:28:5d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s20f0u1u3i5
4: wifi0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether de:5f:48:3b:4a:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 7c:b5:66:65:be:72
    altname wlp1s0
5: management@lan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:4d:ad:02:ac:fd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.30.63/24 metric 2048 brd 10.0.30.255 scope global dynamic management
       valid_lft 4764sec preferred_lft 4764sec
    inet6 x:x:x:7030:a44f:5260:dda1:efdd/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 3282sec preferred_lft 1482sec
    inet6 x:x:x:7030:f64d:adff:fe02:acfd/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 3282sec preferred_lft 1482sec
    inet6 fe80::f64d:adff:fe02:acfd/64 scope link proto kernel_ll
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: ztzlggwhus: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 2800 qdisc fq state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether x:x:x:x:x:x brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.26.x.x/16 brd 172.26.255.255 scope global ztzlggwhus
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x/88 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 x:x:x::1/40 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::x:x:x/64 scope link proto kernel_ll
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

➜ ip r
default via 10.0.0.254 dev lan0 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.55 metric 1024
10.0.0.0/24 dev lan0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.55 metric 1024
10.0.0.254 dev lan0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.0.55 metric 1024
10.0.30.0/24 dev management proto kernel scope link src 10.0.30.63 metric 2048
172.26.x.x/16 dev ztzlggwhus proto kernel scope link src 172.26.x.x
```

When I run `tcpdump` on the management interface from either the router or the laptop, I see normal IPv6 NDP packets, and then a whole bunch of ARP requests like this:

```
➜ sudo tcpdump -s 1500 -i management -nn -vv
tcpdump: listening on management, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 1500 bytes
00:29:12.774606 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 201.206.191.36 tell 10.0.30.63, length 28
00:29:12.775206 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 50.7.252.138 tell 10.0.30.63, length 28
00:29:12.775291 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 103.195.103.66 tell 10.0.30.63, length 28
00:29:12.775434 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 84.17.53.155 tell 10.0.30.63, length 28
00:29:12.775633 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 104.194.8.134 tell 10.0.30.63, length 28
00:29:13.792744 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 104.194.8.134 tell 10.0.30.63, length 28
00:29:13.792774 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 84.17.53.155 tell 10.0.30.63, length 28
00:29:13.792779 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 103.195.103.66 tell 10.0.30.63, length 28
00:29:13.792784 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 50.7.252.138 tell 10.0.30.63, length 28
00:29:13.792788 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 201.206.191.36 tell 10.0.30.63, length 28
00:29:14.816739 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 201.206.191.36 tell 10.0.30.63, length 28
00:29:14.816779 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 50.7.252.138 tell 10.0.30.63, length 28
00:29:14.816784 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 103.195.103.66 tell 10.0.30.63, length 28
00:29:14.816788 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 84.17.53.155 tell 10.0.30.63, length 28
00:29:14.816792 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 104.194.8.134 tell 10.0.30.63, length 28
00:29:17.780657 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 70.57.30.7 tell 10.0.30.63, length 28
00:29:18.784750 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 70.57.30.7 tell 10.0.30.63, length 28
00:29:19.808723 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 70.57.30.7 tell 10.0.30.63, length 28
^C
18 packets captured
18 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Which I find very strange since those addresses are clearly outside of the subnet and so I would have expected that for any requests to those addresses, the kernel would simply forward the packet to the default gateway (`10.0.0.254` on `lan0`) and not even try to send it out on the `management` interface.

So I'm trying to understand why these weird ARP requests for addresses outside of the subnet are being sent, and whether I have configured something wrongly.

Comment: are there any iptables/nftable rules that could interfere with theses packets?